# Remove Daylight/Standard time character using %Z and `strftime`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

Is it possible to remove the Daylight/Standard time indicator using `strftime` and `%Z`?

I'm using localization inside of a Rails app and its reporting the timezone as "PDT" and "PST" - but really all I want is "PT" - without the D or the S.  I don't see a Format Directive for this in `strftime`'s [documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) - so I'm wondering if I need to use `gsub` to take it out or if there's another undocumented Format Directive I should use instead?

Code:

```
I18n.localize(foo.created_at, format: '%A %-l%P %Z')
```

Output:

```
Wednesday 1pm PDT
```

Desired Output:

```
Wednesday 1pm PT
```

application.rb config:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: It's not possible, you have to remove them manipulating the string.

Comment: Thought so.  I wanted to ask the SO community to see if there was a better way first.